# Make 2 column section extend full width with different colors, but retain container for content?

Tags: html, css

I need to build a 50/50 column section where each column has a different background color, and each one extends to the edge of the screen. I have text in each column (left aligned and right aligned respectively), but I want the text itself to be contained in a 1200px container that's centered on the page.

Here is a mockup of what I'm trying to achieve, where the yellow outline indicates the 1200px centered container.

[image]

Below is an example of my setup currently, but the problem is that the background color only applies to the columns and doesn't extend to the edge of the screen. How can I tackle this problem?

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 1200px; margin:0 auto;">
  <div class="red-col left">
    Left Aligned Text
  </div>
  <div class="blue-col right">
    Right Aligned Text
  </div>
</div>
```